# How does Google Search determine a user's 'Current Region'?

Tags: google-search, localization

How can I tell what region Google Search sees as the *Current Region* and what is that being based on?

This is what I see in 
`Google Search > Other settings > Language & region > Results region`:

[image: Google Search's Regional Settings]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

#### How do I see which region is the "Current Region"?

You can see it in the bottom of Search results page:

[image]

#### What is Google search settings Current Region based on?

> ##### How Google determines your location when you search
>
> When you use Google, like with Maps, Search or Google Assistant, your current location is estimated from several sources, depending on their availability. These sources are used together to determine where you are:
>
> - Your device location
> - Your Google account addresses like from your home or your work
> - Your Google Home app for your speaker, Smart Display, or Smart Clock
> - Your Google products with your previous activity
> - Your internet connection's IP address

*Source*: https://support.google.com/websearch/answer/179386